# PHP - Same Page Call Back Using Post

Tags: php, html, forms, url

I have an array in php containing details to do with an application, for example an id, a name, a date created an invoice and so on.

I am currently displaying to the user the application name as a URL so that ideally when they click it they can see some other details that I can look up from the database based on the attributes above.

I recall during university a few years ago that I can use POST with an html form to send this - correct? However i am a little confused as I don't really need any information to be shown to the user in terms of a form - for example no input box is needed, the submit button really is the link I am providing and so on.

In this case how do I create a solution using my URL approach to call back to the current page

For example something like this works with GET

```
<a href="./display.php?data=Data1&data2=Data120">Click here</a>


<?php
    if(isset($_GET["data"]) && isset($_GET["data2"]))
    {
        $data = $_GET["data"];
        $data2 = $_GET["data2"];
    }
?>
```

But using via GET is not ideal as it will allow others to guess personal information which would be an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use form with hidden element and only visible element is button...

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" />
</form>
```

Something like this...

Answer (score 0):

try passing some parameters using $_GET. That way the user will be able to view some parameters in the ULR page, but you wont need another page to show this user their details.

Answer (score 0):

Then try using jquery to show/hide some page content. for example:

```
<a onClick="document.getElementById('option1').style.display='block';">click me</a> 
<div= id='option1' style='display: none;'>
some hidden content. when you click the link, it will be visible
</div>
```